# What is the difference between prompt tuning and prefix tuning?

Tags: deep-learning, fine-tuning, pretrained-models, few-shot-learning, zero-shot-learning

I read *prompt tuning* and *prefix tuning* are two effective mechanisms to leverage frozen language models to perform downstream tasks. What is the difference between the two and how they work really?

Prompt Tuning: https://aclanthology.org/2021.emnlp-main.243/

Prefix-Tuning: https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.00190